# Ordenar Array multidimensional PHP por campo

Tags: php, array

Tengo un array de la siguiente manera y quiero ordenarlos por `hora_inicio`.

```
Array(
    [0] => Array(
            [sala] => Sala1
            [empleado] => empleado1
            [dia] => 13
            [mes] => 06
            [ano] => 2019
            [hora_inicio] => 16:00
            [hora_fin] => 18:00 )
    [1] => Array(
            [sala] => Sala1
            [empleado] => empleado2
            [dia] => 18
            [mes] => 06
            [ano] => 2019
            [hora_inicio] => 09:00
            [hora_fin] => 11:00 )
    [2] => Array(
            [sala] => Sala1
            [empleado] => empleado2
            [dia] => 19
            [mes] => 06
            [ano] => 2019
            [hora_inicio] => 15:00
            [hora_fin] => 17:00 )
    [3] => Array(
            [sala] => Sala1
            [empleado] => empleado3
            [dia] => 13
            [mes] => 06
            [ano] => 2019
            [hora_inicio] => 10:00
            [hora_fin] => 11:00 )
    [4] => Array(
            [sala] => Sala1
            [empleado] => empleado3
            [dia] => 13
            [mes] => 06
            [ano] => 2019
            [hora_inicio] => 12:00
            [hora_fin] => 13:00 )
)
```

Comment: ¿El array está definido así? $arrayReserva=[
 [
  "hora_inicio"=>"10:00", 
  "hora_fin"=>"11:00",
 ],
 [
  "hora_inicio"=>"08:00", 
  "hora_fin"=>"09:00",
 ],
];

Comment: Array(
 [0] => Array(
   [sala] => Sala1
   [empleado] => empleado1
   [dia] => 13
   [mes] => 06
   [ano] => 2019
   [hora_inicio] => 16:00
   [hora_fin] => 18:00 )
 [1] => Array(
   [sala] => Sala1
   [empleado] => empleado2
   [dia] => 18
   [mes] => 06
   [ano] => 2019
   [hora_inicio] => 09:00
   [hora_fin] => 11:00 )
)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solucionado.
Para aquel que le pueda servir, dejo la función `array_multisort` con los parámetros que he puesto y me los ha ordenado por `hora_inicio` ASC (de menor a mayor).

```
array_multisort(array_column($reservaArray, 'hora_inicio'), SORT_ASC, $reservaArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Pues, acabo de hacer la prueba, y parece que `sort()` ordena por el primer elemento de cada subarray. Te paso el código para que lo compruebes:

```
<?php

$arrayReserva=[
    [
        "hora_inicio"=>"10:00", 
        "hora_fin"=>"11:00",
    ],
    [
        "hora_inicio"=>"08:00", 
        "hora_fin"=>"12:00",
    ],
];

sort($arrayReserva);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($arrayReserva);
echo '</pre>';


$arrayReserva=[
    [
        "hora_fin"=>"11:00",
        "hora_inicio"=>"10:00",         
    ],
    [
        "hora_fin"=>"12:00",
        "hora_inicio"=>"08:00",         
    ],
];

sort($arrayReserva);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($arrayReserva);
echo '</pre>';

?>
```

Comment: Me he explicado mal, el array lo tengo de la siguiente manera.

Comment: Array(
 [0] => Array(
   [sala] => Sala1
   [empleado] => empleado1
   [dia] => 13
   [mes] => 06
   [ano] => 2019
   [hora_inicio] => 16:00
   [hora_fin] => 18:00 )
 [1] => Array(
   [sala] => Sala1
   [empleado] => empleado2
   [dia] => 18
   [mes] => 06
   [ano] => 2019
   [hora_inicio] => 09:00
   [hora_fin] => 11:00 )
)