# intento de ordenar array complejo

Tags: php, array, php7, ordenamiento, filtro

***Este post será un poco extenso para poder dar los ejemplos concretos y los escenarios, tratare de ser lo más directo y preciso.***

***El objetivo es poder ordenar/filtrar datos.***

Primero que nada estoy consumiendo un API que me arroja un JSON string con el siguiente formato:

```
{"card_list":[{"name":"Effect Veiler","details":["some text","some text"],"set":{"ETCO-EN100":{"release":"2020-01-19","rarity":{"Starlight":[{"edition":"1st","seller":{"0":{"name":"Vendedor # 1","status":"NM","price":421.25,"stock":true,"main":true},"1":{"name":"Vendedor # 1","status":"LP","price":265.34,"stock":false,"main":true},"3":{"name":"Vendedor # 2","status":"NM","price":400.8,"stock":true,"main":false},"4":{"name":"Vendedor # 3","status":"NM","price":412.68,"stock":true,"main":false}}},{"edition":"unl","seller":{"0":{"name":"Vendedor # 1","status":"NM","price":401.25,"stock":true,"main":true},"1":{"name":"Vendedor # 1","status":"LP","price":245.34,"stock":false,"main":true},"3":{"name":"Vendedor # 2","status":"NM","price":380.8,"stock":true,"main":false},"4":{"name":"Vendedor # 3","status":"NM","price":392.68,"stock":true,"main":false}}}]}},"DREV-EN002":{"release":"2012-05-23","rarity":{"Ultra":[{"edition":"1st","seller":[{"name":"Vendedor # 1","status":"NM","price":35.25,"stock":true,"main":true},{"name":"Vendedor # 1","status":"LP","price":32.34,"stock":false,"main":true}]},{"edition":"unl","seller":[{"name":"Vendedor # 1","status":"NM","price":25.25,"stock":true,"main":true},{"name":"Vendedor # 2","status":"LP","price":21.34,"stock":false,"main":true}]}],"Ultimate":[{"edition":"1st","seller":[{"name":"Vendedor # 1","status":"NM","price":655.25,"stock":true,"main":true},{"name":"Vendedor # 1","status":"LP","price":605.34,"stock":false,"main":true}]},{"edition":"unl","seller":[{"name":"Vendedor # 1","status":"NM","price":580.25,"stock":true,"main":true},{"name":"Vendedor # 2","status":"LP","price":565.34,"stock":false,"main":true}]}]}}}}]}
```

***Una vez que lo recibo lo conbierto en un array, el array resultante luce asi:***

```php
$array = [
    'card_list' => [
        0 => [
            'name'    => 'Effect Veiler',
            'details' => ['some text', 'some text'],
            'set'     => [
                'ETCO-EN100' => [
                    'release' => '2020-01-19',
                    'rarity'  => [
                        'Starlight' => [
                            0 => [
                                'edition' => '1st',
                                'seller'  => [
                                    0 => [
                                        'name'   => 'Vendedor # 1',
                                        'status' => 'NM',
                                        'price'  => 421.25,
                                        'stock'  => true,
                                        'main'   => true,
                                    ],
                                    1 => [
                                        'name'   => 'Vendedor # 1',
                                        'status' => 'LP',
                                        'price'  => 265.34,
                                        'stock'  => false,
                                        'main'   => true,
                                    ],
                                    3 => [
                                        'name'   => 'Vendedor # 2',
                                        'status' => 'NM',
                                        'price'  => 400.80,
                                        'stock'  => true,
                                        'main'   => false,
                                    ],
                                    4 => [
                                        'name'   => 'Vendedor # 3',
                                        'status' => 'NM',
                                        'price'  => 412.68,
                                        'stock'  => true,
                                        'main'   => false,
                                    ],
                                ],
                            ],
                            1 => [
                                'edition' => 'unl',
                                'seller'  => [
                                    0 => [
                                        'name'   => 'Vendedor # 1',
                                        'status' => 'NM',
                                        'price'  => 401.25,
                                        'stock'  => true,
                                        'main'   => true,
                                    ],
                                    1 => [
                                        'name'   => 'Vendedor # 1',
                                        'status' => 'LP',
                                        'price'  => 245.34,
                                        'stock'  => false,
                                        'main'   => true,
                                    ],
                                    3 => [
                                        'name'   => 'Vendedor # 2',
                                        'status' => 'NM',
                                        'price'  => 380.80,
                                        'stock'  => true,
                                        'main'   => false,
                                    ],
                                    4 => [
                                        'name'   => 'Vendedor # 3',
                                        'status' => 'NM',
                                        'price'  => 392.68,
                                        'stock'  => true,
                                        'main'   => false,
                                    ],
                                ],
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
                'DREV-EN002' => [
                    'release' => '2012-05-23',
                    'rarity'  => [
                        'Ultra'    => [
                            0 => [
                                'edition' => '1st',
                                'seller'  => [
                                    0 => [
                                        'name'   => 'Vendedor # 1',
                                        'status' => 'NM',
                                        'price'  => 35.25,
                                        'stock'  => true,
                                        'main'   => true,
                                    ],
                                    1 => [
                                        'name'   => 'Vendedor # 1',
                                        'status' => 'LP',
                                        'price'  => 32.34,
                                        'stock'  => false,
                                        'main'   => true,
                                    ],
                                ],
                            ],
                            1 => [
                                'edition' => 'unl',
                                'seller'  => [
                                    0 => [
                                        'name'   => 'Vendedor # 1',
                                        'status' => 'NM',
                                        'price'  => 25.25,
                                        'stock'  => true,
                                        'main'   => true,
                                    ],
                                    1 => [
                                        'name'   => 'Vendedor # 2',
                                        'status' => 'LP',
                                        'price'  => 21.34,
                                        'stock'  => false,
                                        'main'   => true,
                                    ],
                                ],
                            ],
                        ],
                        'Ultimate' => [
                            0 => [
                                'edition' => '1st',
                                'seller'  => [
                                    0 => [
                                        'name'   => 'Vendedor # 1',
                                        'status' => 'NM',
                                        'price'  => 655.25,
                                        'stock'  => true,
                                        'main'   => true,
                                    ],
                                    1 => [
                                        'name'   => 'Vendedor # 1',
                                        'status' => 'LP',
                                        'price'  => 605.34,
                                        'stock'  => false,
                                        'main'   => true,
                                    ],
                                ],
                            ],
                            1 => [
                                'edition' => 'unl',
                                'seller'  => [
                                    0 => [
                                        'name'   => 'Vendedor # 1',
                                        'status' => 'NM',
                                        'price'  => 580.25,
                                        'stock'  => true,
                                        'main'   => true,
                                    ],
                                    1 => [
                                        'name'   => 'Vendedor # 2',
                                        'status' => 'LP',
                                        'price'  => 565.34,
                                        'stock'  => false,
                                        'main'   => true,
                                    ],
                                ],
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
];
```

***Luego trabajando con este array he logrado crear un primer script para imprimirlo:***

Nota: Este script lo he descartado por que no me permite aplicar filtros de ordenamiento.

```php
$buffer = '<table>';

foreach ($array as $key1 => $value1) {
    if (strpos($key1, 'card_list') !== false) {
        foreach ($value1 as $key2 => $value2) {
            foreach ($value2 as $key3 => $value3) {
                //detecting name node
                if (strpos($key3, 'name') !== false) {
                    $buffer .= '<tr><th><h3>' . $value3 . '</h3></th></tr>';
                }
                //detecting details node
                if (strpos($key3, 'details') !== false) {
                    $buffer .= '<tr><th>';
                    foreach ($value3 as $key_detail => $value_detail) {
                        $buffer .= $value_detail . '<br>';
                    }
                    $buffer .= '</th></tr>';
                }

                //detecting set node
                if (strpos($key3, 'set') !== false) {
                    $buffer .= '<tr><th><table border="1">';
                    $buffer .= '<tr>
                                    <th></th>
                                    <th>Code Exp</th>
                                    <th>Edition</th>
                                    <th>Release</th>
                                    <th>Rarity</th>
                                    <th>Seller</th>
                                    <th>Status</th>
                                    <th>Price</th>
                                    <th>In Stock</th>
                                    <th>Cert. Store</th>
                                  </tr>';
                    foreach ($value3 as $key_exp => $value_exp) {
                        $code_exp = $key_exp;
                        $release  = $value_exp['release'];
                        foreach ($value_exp['rarity'] as $rarity => $rarity_detail) {
                            foreach ($rarity_detail as $num_reg => $edition_data) {
                                $edition = $edition_data['edition'];
                                foreach ($edition_data['seller'] as $num_seller => $seller_detail) {
                                    $buffer .= '<tr>
                                                    <td>' . ($num_seller + 1) . '</td>
                                                    <td>' . $code_exp . '</td>
                                                    <td>' . $edition . '</td>
                                                    <td>' . $release . '</td>
                                                    <td>' . $rarity . '</td>
                                                    <td>' . $seller_detail['name'] . '</td>
                                                    <td>' . $seller_detail['status'] . '</td>
                                                    <td>' . $seller_detail['price'] . '</td>
                                                    <td>' . ($seller_detail['stock'] ? 'In Stock' : 'Out of Stock') . '</td>
                                                    <td>' . ($seller_detail['main'] ? 'Not' : 'Yes') . '</td>
                                                  </tr>';
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    $buffer .= '</table></th></tr> ';
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
$buffer .= '</table > ';

echo $buffer;
```

***output (html):***
Nota: uso una imagen para evitar el limite de caracteres por post

[image: output]

entonces la Salida de este parte del script aunque no tiene filtros aplicados es correcta; ya que las filas estan ordenadas por grupo o la columna ***Code Exp***: ['set']['Indice'].

**Pero aplicar los siguientes filtro se me ha compliado:**

| Node | criteria | tipe of filter data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| name | Sort by Name Order string | Sort by string |
| rarity | Sort by Rarity Order string give | Array with string in order |
| price | Sort by price Order on floats | sort float |
| status | include/exclude by Status | Include and Sort by Status Array |
| main | include/exclude by Main store | Include by Boolean |
| stock | Skip Out of Stock | Exlude if and stock is false |

**OJO:** no espero que me hagan el trabajo de todo estos filtros busco un ejemplo que me ayude a entender e implemtar los filtros por mi cuenta, cosa que no logro encontrar.

***Que he intentado:***

He buscado la manera de ordenar o pasar varias formas de ordenamiento a este array que estoy recibiendo de una api, y literalmente se ha convertido en un dolor de huevo, no veo la manera de lograrlo con los ejemplo que he encontrado en el sitio y las explicaciones de otras respuestas, en mi intento he tratado de hacer el ordenamiento tomando como referencia la columna `prod_price`:

**Opcion 1:**

```php
array_multisort(array_column($array, 'price'), $array);
```

> Warning: array_multisort(): Array sizes are inconsistent in

**Opcion 2:**

```php
usort($array, fn($a, $b) => $a['price'] <=> $b['price']);
```

> Output en Blanco ... no se que paso aqui...

**Opcion 3:**

```php
usort($array, function ($a, $b) {
    return $b['price'] - $a['price'];
});
```

> Output en Blanco ... no se que paso aqui...

**Links relacionados:**
[Link1](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/529930/php-error-array-sizes-are-inconsistent-al-ordenar-arreglo-multidimensional-de) 
[Link2](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/271747/ordenar-array-multidimensional-php-por-campo)

***Argumentos***
Como podran ver en mis primero ejemplo he tratado de ordenar mediante el nodo `price` y no lo he logrado... he creado otros script de ejemplo para minificar la complejidad del array:

https://wtools.io/php-sandbox/bIbX

pero tampoco me han funcionado.

Mis dudas en cuestion son:

1. De todo esto solo me interesa saber ordenar ascendente y descendente por columna.
2. Y cómo aplicar un ordenamiento basado en una cadena/float como la columna `price` o `prod_price`.

***Update:***

he logrado un pequeño pero sustancial avance, he podido aplicar array_multisort, aunque sigo sin estar seguro de que este 100% correcto y hasta el punto que he llegado esta a un 90%:

primero he creado un script para minimizar el array de la siguiente forma:

```php
$card_list = [];

foreach ($array as $key1 => $value1) {
    if (strpos($key1, 'card_list') !== false) {
        foreach ($value1 as $key2 => $value2) {
            foreach ($value2 as $key3 => $value3) {
                //detecting name node
                if (strpos($key3, 'name') !== false) {
                    $card_list[$key2]['card_name'] = $value3;
                }
                //detecting details node
                if (strpos($key3, 'details') !== false) {
                    $card_list[$key2]['detail'] = implode('<br>', $value3);
                }
                //detecting set node
                if (strpos($key3, 'set') !== false) {
                    $card_list[$key2]['list'] = [];
                    foreach ($value3 as $key_exp => $value_exp) {
                        $code_exp = $key_exp;
                        $release  = $value_exp['release'];
                        foreach ($value_exp['rarity'] as $rarity => $rarity_detail) {
                            foreach ($rarity_detail as $num_reg => $edition_data) {
                                $edition = $edition_data['edition'];
                                foreach ($edition_data['seller'] as $num_seller => $seller_detail) {
                                    $card_list[$key2]['list'][] = [
                                        'code_exp'    => $code_exp,
                                        'edition'     => $edition,
                                        'release'     => $release,
                                        'rarity'      => $rarity,
                                        'seller_name' => $seller_detail['name'],
                                        'prod_status' => $seller_detail['status'],
                                        'prod_price'  => $seller_detail['price'],
                                        'prod_stock'  => ($seller_detail['stock'] ? 'In Stock' : 'Out of Stock'),
                                        'main_store'  => ($seller_detail['main'] ? 'Not' : 'Yes'),
                                    ];
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Una vez que el array es de menos dimenciones he logrado recorrerlo de la siguiente forma:

```php
$buffer = '<table>';

foreach ($card_list as $key => $reg) {
    foreach ($reg as $index => $data) {
        if (strpos($index, 'card_name') !== false) {
            $buffer .= '<tr><th><h3>' . $data . '</h3></th></tr>';
        }
        if (strpos($index, 'details') !== false) {
            $buffer .= '<tr><th><h3>' . $data . '</h3></th></tr>';
        }
        if (strpos($index, 'list') !== false) {
            $buffer .= '<tr><th><table border="1">
                                  <tr>
                                    <th></th>
                                    <th>Code Exp</th>
                                    <th>Edition</th>
                                    <th>Release</th>
                                    <th>Rarity</th>
                                    <th>Seller</th>
                                    <th>Status</th>
                                    <th>Price</th>
                                    <th>In Stock</th>
                                    <th>Cert. Store</th>
                                  </tr>';
            //array_multisort();


            $dict      = array_flip(['all', 'NM', 'LP', 'MP', 'HP', 'DMG']);
            $positions = array_map(function ($elem) use ($dict) {
                return $dict[$elem['prod_status']] ?? INF;
            }, $data);

            $filer_code_exp    = [];
            $filer_edition     = [];
            $filer_release     = [];
            $filer_rarity      = [];
            $filer_seller_name = [];
            $filer_prod_status = [];
            $filer_prod_price  = [];
            $filer_prod_stock  = [];
            $filer_main_store  = [];

            foreach ($data as $num_reg => $car_list) {
                $filer_code_exp[$num_reg]    = $car_list['code_exp'];
                $filer_edition[$num_reg]     = $car_list['edition'];
                $filer_release[$num_reg]     = $car_list['release'];
                $filer_rarity[$num_reg]      = $car_list['rarity'];
                $filer_seller_name[$num_reg] = $car_list['seller_name'];
                $filer_prod_status[$num_reg] = $car_list['prod_status']; //$positions;
                $filer_prod_price[$num_reg]  = $car_list['prod_price'];
                $filer_prod_stock[$num_reg]  = $car_list['main_store'];
            }
            array_multisort(
                $filer_release, SORT_DESC,
                $filer_edition, SORT_ASC,
                $filer_rarity, SORT_DESC,
                $filer_prod_status, SORT_DESC,
                $filer_prod_price, SORT_ASC,
                $data
            );

            foreach ($data as $num_reg => $car_list) {
                $buffer .= '<tr>
                                <td>' . ($num_reg + 1) . '</td>
                                <td>' . $car_list['code_exp'] . '</td>
                                <td>' . $car_list['edition'] . '</td>
                                <td>' . $car_list['release'] . '</td>
                                <td>' . $car_list['rarity'] . '</td>
                                <td>' . $car_list['seller_name'] . '</td>
                                <td>' . $car_list['prod_status'] . '</td>
                                <td>' . $car_list['prod_price'] . '</td>
                                <td>' . $car_list['prod_stock'] . '</td>
                                <td>' . $car_list['main_store'] . '</td>
                             </tr>';
            }
            $buffer .= '</table></th></tr>';
        }
    }
}
$buffer .= '</table > ';

echo $buffer;
```

con esto paso de este output:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A este Otro output en donde ya hay un indicio del ordenamiento por precio por lo menos o de aquellos campos que puedo ordenar por string:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego de esto como les decia esta a un 90%, lo que ahora me hace falta es poder aplicar un orden predefinido a la columana: `prod_status`.

He intentando con:

```php
$dict      = array_flip(['all', 'NM', 'LP', 'MP', 'HP', 'DMG']);
$positions = array_map(function ($elem) use ($dict) {
    return $dict[$elem['prod_status']] ?? INF;
}, $data);
```

Para pasarlo como filtro en:

```php
$filer_prod_status[$num_reg] = $positions;
```

Pero no me funciona ... estoy seguro que es la idea correcta, pero tengo algun error ...

Comment: Convierte el objeto en arreglo, con el que que podrás conseguir ordenamientos complejos usando [`usort()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.usort.php).

Comment: @Sal ya me hice un apaño pero me tope con otro problema ...

Comment: Cuando dices "ordenar por precio" que quisieras obtener? quisieras obtener el elemento con price 655 sin importar que pertenezca a un "code exp" distinto? es decir, quieres es ordenar los precios solo dentro de cada "code exp" o en general? Porque lo que yo creo que deberías hacer es generar una estructura similar a la tabla que generas para imprimir (pero solo en datos) y luego sobre esos datos si ordenas y filtras

Comment: @Pipe le he metido un update al post para que sepas que habances llevo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Espero que esto le sirva a alguien:

1. El array inicial es muy complejo para ser manipulado y trabajado por `array_multisort` es necesario minimisarlo entonces a partir de la estructura que presente podemos ejecutar este script para minimisarlo:

```php
$card_list = [];

foreach ($cards as $key1 => $value1) {
    if (strpos($key1, 'card_list') !== false) {
        foreach ($value1 as $key2 => $value2) {
            foreach ($value2 as $key3 => $value3) {
                //detecting name node
                if (strpos($key3, 'name') !== false) {
                    $card_list[$key2]['card_name'] = $value3;
                }
                //detecting details node
                if (strpos($key3, 'details') !== false) {
                    $card_list[$key2]['detail'] = implode('<br>', $value3);
                }
                //detecting set node
                if (strpos($key3, 'set') !== false) {
                    $card_list[$key2]['list'] = [];
                    foreach ($value3 as $key_exp => $value_exp) {
                        $code_exp = $key_exp;
                        $release  = $value_exp['release'];
                        foreach ($value_exp['rarity'] as $rarity => $rarity_detail) {
                            foreach ($rarity_detail as $num_reg => $edition_data) {
                                $edition = $edition_data['edition'];
                                foreach ($edition_data['seller'] as $num_seller => $seller_detail) {
                                    $card_list[$key2]['list'][] = [
                                        'code_exp'    => $code_exp,
                                        'edition'     => $edition,
                                        'release'     => $release,
                                        'rarity'      => $rarity,
                                        'seller_name' => $seller_detail['name'],
                                        'prod_status' => $seller_detail['status'],
                                        'prod_price'  => $seller_detail['price'],
                                        'prod_stock'  => ($seller_detail['stock'] ? 'In Stock' : 'Out of Stock'),
                                        'main_store'  => ($seller_detail['main'] ? 'Not' : 'Yes'),
                                    ];
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

2. luego de esto podemos recorrerlo y aplicarle los filtros al momemtno de llegar al nodo `list`:

```php
$buffer = '<table>';

foreach ($card_list as $key => $reg) {
    foreach ($reg as $index => $data) {
        if (strpos($index, 'card_name') !== false) {
            $buffer .= '<tr><th><h3>' . $data . '</h3></th></tr>';
        }
        if (strpos($index, 'details') !== false) {
            $buffer .= '<tr><th><h3>' . $data . '</h3></th></tr>';
        }
        if (strpos($index, 'list') !== false) {
            $buffer .= '<tr><th><table border="1">
                                  <tr>
                                    <th></th>
                                    <th>Code Exp</th>
                                    <th>Edition</th>
                                    <th>Release</th>
                                    <th>Rarity</th>
                                    <th>Seller</th>
                                    <th>Status</th>
                                    <th>Price</th>
                                    <th>In Stock</th>
                                    <th>Cert. Store</th>
                                  </tr>';

            $status_filter = ['NM', 'LP', 'MP', 'HP', 'DMG'];

            $post['filter_status'] = ['NM', 'LP', 'MP', 'HP', 'DMG'];


            $filtered = [];

            if ($post['filter_status'] != 'all') {
                $filtered     = array_diff($status_filter, $post['filter_status']);
                $apply_filter = array_diff($status_filter, $filtered);
            }

            foreach ($data as $key => $node) {
                if (!in_array($node['prod_status'], $apply_filter)) {
                    unset($data[$key]);
                }
            }


            $filer_code_exp    = [];
            $filer_edition     = [];
            $filer_release     = [];
            $filer_rarity      = [];
            $filer_seller_name = [];
            $filer_prod_status = [];
            $filer_prod_price  = [];
            $filer_prod_stock  = [];
            $filer_main_store  = [];

            foreach ($data as $num_reg => $car_list) {
                $filer_prod_status[$num_reg] = array_flip($status_filter)[$car_list['prod_status']] ?? INF;
            }

            foreach ($data as $num_reg => $car_list) {
                $filer_code_exp[$num_reg]    = $car_list['code_exp'];
                $filer_edition[$num_reg]     = $car_list['edition'];
                $filer_release[$num_reg]     = $car_list['release'];
                $filer_rarity[$num_reg]      = $car_list['rarity'];
                $filer_seller_name[$num_reg] = $car_list['seller_name'];
                $filer_prod_price[$num_reg]  = $car_list['prod_price'];
                $filer_prod_stock[$num_reg]  = $car_list['main_store'];
            }

            array_multisort(

                $filer_release,
                SORT_DESC,
                $filer_edition,
                SORT_ASC,
                $filer_rarity,
                SORT_DESC,
                $filer_prod_status,
                SORT_ASC,
                $filer_prod_price,
                SORT_ASC,
                
                $data
            );

            foreach ($data as $num_reg => $car_list) {
                $buffer .= '<tr>
                                <td>' . ($num_reg + 1) . '</td>
                                <td>' . $car_list['code_exp'] . '</td>
                                <td>' . $car_list['edition'] . '</td>
                                <td>' . $car_list['release'] . '</td>
                                <td>' . $car_list['rarity'] . '</td>
                                <td>' . $car_list['seller_name'] . '</td>
                                <td>' . $car_list['prod_status'] . '</td>
                                <td>' . $car_list['prod_price'] . '</td>
                                <td>' . $car_list['prod_stock'] . '</td>
                                <td>' . $car_list['main_store'] . '</td>
                             </tr>';
            }
            $buffer .= '</table></th></tr>';
        }
    }
}
$buffer .= '</table > ';

echo $buffer;
```

Nota: al momento de aplicar los filtro existe una cualidad particular y es que el filtro de estatus debe cumplir tambien la utilidad de exluir registro por eso veran que se eliminan datos y que al final aplica un orden predefino.

Asumo que este codigo se puede re-factorizar y mejorar ... cosa que de momento se escapa de mis manos. pero ya es funcional